# Random color change while mouse hovers over grid of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the divs to a random color with the mouseover function, however I'm unable to find a clear answer on what I need to change to make that happen.  Any ideas?  Here's my original script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
        $('<div />', {
            'class': 'sameDiv',
            'id': 'div' + i
        }).appendTo('body');
    }
});

$('.sameDiv').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(200, Math.random());
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, Math.random());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smugfox/7vx3W/3/

Comment: `Math.random()` provide values between 0 and 1.  You obviously need to do something to convert this to useful hex or RGB values. I don't see where you have made an effort to do so.  You also don't seem to be attempting to change color at all.

Comment: @MikeBrant a CV is worth 1000 words ;)

Answer (score 4):

In your `mouseout` function, you can generate three random values for the `rgb` color.

```
$(this).css("background","rgb("+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+")")
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/48KzD/)

Comment: Best answer here so far, but it will never give a solid white color. Try 256 instead of 255.

Comment: I should have noticed that. Thank you @DaggNabbit

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your fiddle. Here is the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
        $('<div />', {
            'class': 'cell',
                'id': 'div' + i
        }).appendTo('body');
    }
});

$('.cell').mouseover(function () {
    var randomColor = '#' + (function co(lor){   return (lor +=
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
  && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); })('');
    $(this).css("background-color", randomColor);
});
```

[Here is the fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/7vx3W/14/)

Comment: How can this generate a color brighter than `#999999`? What if `Math.random` returns something like 0.00001? What about 0.0000001, that would produce "0.0999"

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
$('.cell').mouseover(function () {
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 16777216)).toString(16);
    $(this).css("background-color",randomColor);
});
```

The transition effect should be achievable via CSS transition.

16777216 is 16^6, the range of values represented by a 6-digit hex. toString(16) converts the decimal value to hex.

**ETA:**

For correctness, this should account for leading zeroes when the generated value is very low. Failing to do so will result in some leading-zero colors (0A6E7A) being replaced with trailing-zero colors (A6E7A0).

```
$('.cell').mouseover(function () {
    var randomColor = "0" + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 16777216)).toString(16));
    $(this).css("background-color","#" + randomColor.substr(randomColor.length - 6));
});
```

Comment: What if `Math.random` returns something like 0.01?

Comment: Hmm, nice catch. I omitted left-padding with 0s in the case of a low value.

Comment: @ElliotM's answer is more concise, but fixed this one for posterity.

Comment: I don't think your edit actually works, does it? Try replacing Math.random() with a very small value. I think you need something like this: `(Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0).toString(16).replace(/.*/, function(x){ return x.length < 6 ? Array(7 - x.length).join('0') + x : x })`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tried giving the background color to div

Here is my code -

```
$('.cell').mouseover(function () {
    var randomColor ='#'+ ('000000'+(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF<<0 ).toString( 16 )).slice(-6);
    $(this).css("background-color",randomColor);
});
```

Check [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8LVV/)

Comment: How can this produce a color brighter than `#999999` or darker than `#100000`?

Comment: Close, but the brightest color it can produce is `#fffffe`. You need `0x1000000` instead of `0xFFFFFF` (that `slice` trick is pretty clever by the way, nice work) :)